# Searching a SQLite database which contains cyrillic data

Tags: android, sqlite, search, utf-8

I have a problem searching my SQLite database, which contains data written with cyrillic characters. If the key word is also cyrillic, then everything is ok, but if not, then I can`t get the result in my Android application.

Does anyone have an idea how can I implement searching the cyrilic data no matter the charset of the keyword? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> If you use UTF8 encode, There will be no problem.

Actually not. String comparison works only with ascii characters (sort, upper, lower and like). If you are using non-ascii chars you should install plugin, which is like whole SQLite in size. [Proof](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18).

If you are interested in cyrillic symbols, try this [link](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122408/).

Answer (score 1):

If you use UTF8 encode, There will be no problem.