# search to the table to be case insensitive

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
golang
DB.Select("name, vin_id").Where("UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER(?)", "%"+name+"%").Find(&vins)
```

Why is this working???
Golang GORM

```
SQL
select * from Table_Name
where  UPPER(Column_Name) = UPPER('mY Any Value')
```

I want the search to the table to be case insensitive

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Mattia Righetti
Sqlite3

Comment: `code` r.DB.Select("name, vin_id").Where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", strings.ToLower("%"+name+"%")).Find(&vins)
This also doesn't work(((

Comment: The `like` statement is case-insensitive by default, [sqlite FAQ](https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q18)

Comment: @Mattia Righetti
I did it through COLLATE СOCASE but it only works with ASCII, but I need it to work with Cyrillic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176618/searching-a-sqlite-database-which-contains-cyrillic-data